# What does it mean when a char or wchar_t == -1?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio why would one compare the value of a character (previously a char, now a wchar_t) to the value of -1?

I have a project with multiple invalid checks against -1:

```
TCHAR ch;
...
if(ch==-1)
```

Coverity is telling me that ""ch == -1" is always false regardless of the values of its operands."

Now, this was originally written to use char values instead of wchar_t, and was upgraded when unicode support was needed.  I need to figure out why the "char ch;" was being checked against -1 so that I can make a similar check against the wchar_t.

Comment: It means end-of-file (`EOF`).

Comment: *usually* means EOF or some kind of error. Update your code with where you're getting the value from would allow us to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer constant `EOF`is typically #defined to `-1`. If that is inded what your code is checking (depends on where `ch` came from), then the corresponding `wchar_t` comparison would be to `WEOF`, and the appropriate Windows TCHAR macro seems to be [_TEOF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z94kex77.aspx).

PS: As absolutely correctly pointed out in comments, if a value was converted to `char` or to `wchar_t`, it is too late to compare it to `EOF` or `WEOF`: plenty of encodings use the char `'\xff'` as a valid letter, and that becomes indistinguishable from EOF after such conversion. The code is simply wrong: the variable `ch` needs to have type `int`/`wint_t`/`_TINT` for any such comparison to be valid.

Comment: Interesting.  The current code is actually checking against both -1 and EOF:
    if(ch==-1 || ch == (TCHAR)EOF)

Comment: I think this answer is wrong; it certainly is according to the C++ standard.  (But Microsoft have been known to do things in very non-standard ways.)  You can no more compare a `wchar_t` to `WEOF` than you can compare a `char` to `EOF`.  You need to use `wint_t` when comparing to `WEOF` (and the quoted link says that `_TEOF` evaluates to either `EOF` or `WEOF`, and so cannot be compared with a `TCHAR`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze you're completely right about `wint_t`! I was going to mention when I opened with 'integer constant EOF', but had to cut short.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, `-1`/`255` is associated to `EOF`

Comment: The standard requires `EOF` to be negative, so it can never be 255.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `TCHAR`?  If it is an unsigned type really
smaller than `int`, the expression can never be be true, since
integral promotion will occur, resulting in a large positive
integer, but still something less than `UINT_MAX`, where as `-1`
is `UINT_MAX`.  (If `TCHAR` is something like `unsigned short`,
for example, it can typically have values in the range 
0...65365, which will convert to an `int` or an `unsigned int`
without changing the value.  -1, on the other hand, will
typically convert to something like 4294967295 when converted to
unsigned.)

If you're checking for end of file (e.g. after an
`std::iwstream.get()`), then you should do so *before*
converting the results from `int`.  Even with `char`, it doesn't
work; if plain `char` is unsigned, then it can never be -1, and
if it is signed, then one valid character (`ÿ` in ISO 8859-1)
will appear to be end of file.